# Implementing Twitter Login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I want to implement a Twitter login in my project. My project is coded in CodeIgniter.
Can somebody give me a step by step process to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just refer the following links- [integrating-twitter-api-with-codeigniter](http://amiworks.co.in/talk/integrating-twitter-api-with-codeigniter/) and

[Auth---3rd-Party-Authentication](https://github.com/ericbae/Tank-Auth---3rd-Party-Authentication-Project)

Answer (score 2):

```
//use  Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth
//https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth
//download url: https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth/archive/master.zip
//Usage

  //  There are two ways to load library to Codeigniter. Automatically within ./config/autoload.php or directly in your controller by adding this line:

    $this->load->library('twitteroauth');

    //Create an instance:

    $connection = $this->twitteroauth->create($consumer, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);

    //Verify your authentication details:

    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

    //Send a message:

    $data = array(
        'status' => $message,
        'in_reply_to_status_id' => $in_reply_to
    );
    $result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this oauth library by philsturgeon [oauth](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth)